# How can I pass a string to a component and make a import in date-fns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date-fns

Im creating a datepicker component in React with typescript and my objective is to call The component

```
 <Datepicker locale="pt-br" />
```

and pass like a string the Locale instead to import it and pass.
And when this string arrives The datepicker component Will make The dynamic import.

1- Its possible to type all locales using the library date-fns with a import type? Or I have to declare all strings manually like:

```
type Locale = {
   locale: 'ptBR' | 'enUS' | 'etc...'
}
```

2- Its possible to recive this string and make the import into the component?

The reason I dont want to import directly the locale like:

```
import {ptBR} from 'date-fns/locale'
```

and pass it as props, is because later I will create a library and i dont want that the user to install date-fns too to only pass this import

If is this possible tell me please, thank you guys.

Comment: The dynamic import may not be supported by the build engine of the project that will consume your library. Or it may require special directives to know what to pre-bundle. Better stick to simply receive explicitly the locale object. If your library depends on `date-fns`, the consumer project will have it installed automatically with your library anyway.